# Enlarging tab image in android

Tags: android, tabs

I implemented tabs. In which I have set the background for each tabs using

```
getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabimg);
```

Now When I select the particular tab I want to enlarge the image of the tab like i it has shown in image.

[image]

Is it possible in android.

If yes, then how? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u tried getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener where u can change the background img

Comment: No I haven't tried. Will try now. But my main question is can we enlarge the image as it is shown in image posted?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find anything. So In this case if anyone else also have the same issue, so what I have done. I have taken a image till the icon and the next image strip covering that text on that respective position and that strip I have set in linear layout. So now if I click on the tab the image look exactly like shown in the photo.